# Mapping on useState object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I was trying to convert my class based component to functional style. I have this code:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null);
const [roomList, setRoomList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  setRoomList(props.onFetchRooms(props.token));
}, [props]);

  let roomLists = <Spinner />;
  if (!props.loading) {
    roomLists = roomList.map(room => <Room key={room._id} roomName={room.name} />);
  }
```

Previously I had:

```
class Rooms extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchRooms(this.props.token);
  }

  render() {
    let roomList = <Spinner />;
    if (!this.props.loading) {
      roomList = this.props.rooms.map(room => <Room key={room._id} roomName={room.name} />);
    }
```

The `onFetchRooms` is a function I am using from Redux in `mapDispatchToProps`. And `rooms` is also coming from the Redux store in `mapStateToProps` With the above new code, I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong please?

I have also tried without using state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.onFetchRooms(props.token);
  }, [props]);

  let roomList = <Spinner />;
  if (!props.loading) {
    roomList = props.rooms.map(room => <Room key={room._id} roomName={room.name} />);
  }
```

But that goes into infinite loop.

Comment: setRoomList(props.onFetchRooms(props.token)); - what is onFetchRooms returning ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you're probably starting the "Functional" version of your component like this:

```
const Rooms = (props) => {
    ...
}
```

Instead, why don't you destructure `props` like this:

```
const Rooms = ({onFetchRooms, rooms, token}) => {
    ...
}
```

Now you can do this in your `useEffect` dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onFetchRooms(token);
}, [onFetchRooms, token]);
```

This should make the infinite loop stop happening.

**Note**: Sometimes to get rid of the *"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array."* error, you "can" use:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

For example, if you only want to add `token` in your dependency array and not worry about `onFetchRooms`, a function that will never change (i assume)

Comment: But then how do I use other props I need like props.loading?

Comment: @rgyfhjdh you can add those prop names inside the first `{...}` where you declare your component - like this: `({loading, onFetchRooms, rooms, token})`. Additionally, you could do `({onFetchRooms, rooms, token, ...props})` to keep the _rest_ of your props in the `props` variable still

Comment: @rgyfhjdh here's documentation on the [`rest`](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread()) syntax and more about [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

useEffect set dependency array to []

**try this**

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.onFetchRooms(props.token);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Yes, but I get `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Answer (score 0):

I think the `props` object will change for each rerender (that's why you get an infinite loop).
You should declare each variables individually into the array :

```
const {onFetchRooms, token} = props;
useEffect(() => onFetchRooms(token), [onFetchRooms, token]);
```